# Apache proxy: Allow remote server access to specific endpoint

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache2

I have a apache reverse proxy set up which works beautifully, only allowing my own IP:

```
<Proxy http://192.168.0.184:8080*>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from my.own.ip.which.works
</Proxy>
```

I want to be able to add a second rule allowing bitbucket.org's servers access to specifically `/bitbucket-hook/`:

```
#allow bitbucket.org access to bitbucket/webhook endpoint
<Proxy http://192.168.0.184:8080/bitbucket-hook/>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Allow from *.compute-1.amazonaws.com
</Proxy>
```

but everything ends up with a 403:

> `ec2-18-234-32-224.compute-1.amazonaws.com - - [10/Nov/2019:22:13:02 +0100] "POST /bitbucket-hook/ HTTP/1.1" 403 3869 "-" "Bitbucket-Webhooks/2.0"`

I assume that `*.compute-1.amazonaws.com` should do it. But this doesn't work...

what can I do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a location statement like this:

```
# Allow bitbucket.org access to bitbucket/webhook endpoint
<Location /bitbucket-hook>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from compute-1.amazonaws.com
</Location>
```

Note that any subdomain which is below `compute-1.amazonaws.com` will satisfy this rule.